# How to pass React component as regular JS to react-test-renderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I see only examples with components in JSX.

But how to pass a component as regular JS `React.createElement()` instead of JSX something like

```
const testRenderer = ReactTestRenderer.create(
    React.createElement('div', null, 'Text');
);
```

Now with this code I get the error

> missing ) after argument list

ps. React on Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you would do it. (Meaning almost like you did it)
(https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)
But you have an extra semicolon inside the create argument list.

```js
const testRenderer = ReactTestRenderer.create(
    React.createElement('div', null, 'Text')
);
```